# How to use Bootstrap 4 validation pseudo-classes (:valid, :invalid) with Angular 5 custom validations?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-validation

Bootstrap 4 validation styles are based on `form-control:valid` or `form-control:invalid`. Angular offers the possibility to add any custom class when a field is in error.

If i follow the spec:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

I can also add `.form-control.is-invalid` class to my `input` element.
However, using a custom validator with this strategy gives i kinda merged results; `form-control is-invalid :valid`

That seems to give more importance to `:valid`, which show my element to be shown as valid, but the related `invalid-feedback` is appearing okay!

I'm kinda lost.

### EDIT

Here's a demo plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/0kxGpRz3JY3ixJbYqRZr?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your demo is working perfectly fine , Only issue here is with class name and style

---

You need to remove `was-validated` class from the `form` tag and keep it as below :

```
class="needs-validation"
```

---

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/HpXORfzaj3f6zAV8oZny?p=preview)**